# Could this VBA Duplicate Marker Be Better?

Tags: excel, vba

Wrote this VBA script just to scan through a spreadsheet and format duplicates by filling their background box. Was just curious if this code could be more efficient. I've been using this script for multiple excel files with slightly different changes in some (hence the unused colNum).

I've tried using Range but had a bit difficulty moving it and comparing it to previous cells.

```
Private Sub MarkDupes()

Worksheets("Test").Activate

Dim rowNum As Long, colNum As Long, rowBelow As Long

'Following loop searches the predetermined column for values
For rowNum = 2 To 1206
   rowBelow = rowNum + 1
   If Cells(rowNum, 1) = Cells(rowBelow, 1) Then
      '38 = salmon
      Cells(rowNum, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
      Cells(rowBelow, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
   End If
Next rowNum
MsgBox "All Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Conditional formatting not an option?

Comment: @BigBen Unfortunately not

Comment: As for efficiency, consider asking that on [codereview.se] - where working code turns into amazing code.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be more efficient:

```
Sub Tester()
    MarkDupes ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A14")
End Sub



Private Sub MarkDupes(rng As Range)

    Const SHADE As Long = 38
    Dim rowNum As Long, cv, n As Long, v, rStart As Long, arr

    arr = rng.Value
    cv = Chr(0) 'a non-value
    For rowNum = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        v = arr(rowNum, 1)
        If v <> cv Then
            If n > 1 Then rng.Cells(rStart).Resize(n, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = SHADE
            rStart = rowNum
            n = 1
            cv = v
        Else
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next rowNum

    If n > 1 Then rng.Cells(rStart).Resize(n, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = SHADE

End Sub
```

Would need some modification depending on how you want to deal with blanks (ie. whether empty is a "value"